# Download file to Folder in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I am new to iPhone,

I made app in which, when user downloads anything it gets downloaded into `DocumentDirectory`

I wants downloading inside my folder which i have created in `DocumentDirectory`

**How to achieve this ?**

I thought I will download file to my `DocumentDirectory` and i will move that file to my folder inside `DocumentDirectory`.

***Is it good practice ?***

**Here is my code snippet,** But still i am unable to move my file.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithString:[url absoluteString]];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:file];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];


    NSString *DestPath=[[[SourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/"]stringByAppendingString:BookCateg]stringByAppendingString:@"/"];

                   if ([fm copyItemAtPath:SourcePath toPath:DestPath error:&error]) 
                   {
                      NSLog(@"Success !");
                   }
                  else{
                      NSLog(@"Fail to Move!");
                   }

}
```

My log shows `Fail to Move!`

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should directly download file to folder of document directory and for that u need to create directory as @iPhone Developer suggested and write file in that directory

For example:

```
  NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/File"];
  error = nil;
  if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ndqatar.mobi/18December/admin/rington/133/QatarDay13.mp3"];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  if(data)
  {
    stringPath = [stringPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];
    [data writeToFile:stringPath atomically:YES];
  }
```

If u want u can move file like this:

```
 NSString *destPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Dest"];
  error = nil;
  if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:destPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
  destPath = [destPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[stringPath lastPathComponent];];

 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:stringPath toPath:destPath error:&error];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Your Folder Name"];

    error = nil;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
NSString *DestPath=[stringPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Your file Name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using string by appending string instead of string by appending path component this will append the path and your file will move there

Enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
Framework: ReactJS
Library: Material-UI
Version: 4.0
```

i try using https://material-ui.com/api/button/
 (add link in href of button) and it works on ipad/iphone/ios safari.

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
<Button href={add_your_link_here} />
```