# How to save html files in Document Directory iOS?

Tags: html, ios, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I have lots of html files and i want to save that html files into an Temporary Directory or an Documents Directory which one is suitable.
I want to save all the html files in the directory Please tell me how to do that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy all html files in your project root folder . then these files can be accessed from nsbundle main bundle.

NSURL *rtfUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@".html"];

[image: then]
[image]

if you want to download all html files to document folder. then you want to access them 
you can take help from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644013/download-file-to-folder-in-iphone)